# sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, xml, activiti

I've created a process definition in an xml file.
In this process I have a step that is suppose to insert data into an mysql database, but when I run my code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: problem evaluating
script: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError:"ReportingUtil"is 
not defined.(<Unknown source>#7) in <Unknown source> at line number 
at 
org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.evaluate(ScriptingEngines.java:89)
...
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError:    
ReferenceError: "ReportingUtil" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#7) in <Unknownsource>
at  
line number 7
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
...
```

I start my process engine from a java class.

This is my process definition:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
  xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"   
  targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn20" id="definitions">
  <process id="simpleEmailProcess" name="simple email">
  <startEvent id="theStart"/>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow1" targetRef="sendMail" sourceRef="theStart"/>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow2" targetRef="waitState" sourceRef="sendMail"/>
   <serviceTask id="sendMail" activiti:class="org.mywebbapp.activiti.RiskProcess" 
  activiti:type="mail">
  <extensionElements>
  <activiti:field name="from" stringValue="workflowact@gmail.com"/>
  <activiti:field name="to" expression="${recipient}"/>
  <activiti:field name="subject" expression="Are you responsible for risk ${riskID}?"/>
  <activiti:field name="html">
  <activiti:expression>
   <![CDATA[ <html> <body> Hello ${name},<br/><br/> Are you responsibible for risk 
   ${riskID}? Please reply to this email by either Y/N.<br/><br/> Kind regards,<br/>   
   The company. </body> </html> ]]>  
    </activiti:expression>
   </activiti:field>
     </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>
    <receiveTask id="waitState" name="wait" />   

    <scriptTask id="generateDataset" name="Execute script" scriptFormat="JavaScript" activiti:autoStoreVariables="false">
           <script><![CDATA[

           importPackage(java.sql);
           importPackage(java.lang);
           importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting.ReportUtil);

           ReportingUtil.executeSelectSqlQuery("insert into risk values ('123', 'user@gmail.com', 'Y')");
      ]]></script>
    </scriptTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" targetRef="generateDataset" sourceRef="waitState"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" targetRef="theEnd" sourceRef="generateDataset"/>
    <endEvent id="theEnd"/>
```

I've read somewhere here on SO that bindings needs to be used?
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting.ReportUtil);
```

You're trying to [import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147207) a class as a package. Use `importClass`.

*I'm assuming Java 8 and Nashorn.*

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I tried using importClass(org.activiti.explorer.reporting); insted of importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting); but that gave me an error saying:    javax.script.ScriptException:     sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Function importClass must be called with a class; had "[JavaPackage org.activiti.explorer.reporting]" instead? I don't understand, I'm all new to js.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using java 6, Nashorn isn't used, Rhino is used.

Comment: Try `importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting);`

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, It made no difference, I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry I meant: `importPackage(Packages.org.activiti.explorer.reporting);`. Or alternatively `importClass(Packages.org.activiti.explorer.reporting.ReportUtil);`

Comment: Tried your suggestion, it still gives me the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a module where I was required to use a particular Util class, similar to what you are using.

Try this,

```
 Packages.org.activiti.explorer.reporting.ReportingUtil.executeSelectSqlQuery(
          "insert into risk values ('123', 'user@gmail.com', 'Y')");]]
```